# Handle legacy URL with Angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building a website where the account page is an Angular.js single page app. So a normal view would have the URL like `localhost:3000/account#/info`

Now say I have to make Angular handle a URL like `localhost:3000/account/?param=value`, how should I set up the router? (I'm using ui-router)

I tried something like

```
$stateProvider.state('my-page', {
  url: '',
  controller: 'MyPageController'
})
```

but it doesn't work. (It only detects `localhost:3000/account?param=value` notice the missing forward slash after `account`)

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because the query part belongs to the server side URL instead of `ui-router` side, you'll need to get it using `$window.location.search`.

Then you can refer [here](http://stevenbenner.com/2010/03/javascript-regex-trick-parse-a-query-string-into-an-object/) to turn it into an object for further use.

Comment: Makes sense, but where should `$window.location.search` exist if `MyPageController` is not even invoked by the router?